# How can I use Jquery to add 'hyphenate' class to P element not working in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5

I am developing a site using Joomla 2.5 and since I'm going to be handing it off to a client who is less than code savvy, I don't want to have to make them try to remember how to add `class=hyphenate` to every `<p>` when they add / update content.

I'm trying to use JQuery to do it but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code that *should* add the class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("p").addClass("hyphenate");
</script>
```

Any input / help is - as always - appreciated!

Thanks,

Cynthia

Comment: Missing document ready handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `script` tag is placed before the `p` elements, you need to wait for the document to be ready - like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").addClass("hyphenate");
});
```

Shorthand version:

```
$(function(){
  $("p").addClass("hyphenate");
});
```

---

**Sidenote**: when mixing libraries, global variables (like the `$`) can get out of hand. So make your own scope, ensuring that the `$` is jQuery:

```
(function($){  // $ = jQuery
  $(function(){
    $("p").addClass("hyphenate");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: For some reason it is still not appending the class to the <p> tag. Here is the url: http://scientific-practices.com/demo/about-the-book

Comment: @Cynthia - looks like you are using mootools as well? Try replacing the `$` with `jQuery` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Also your Jquery May Conflict with Joomla Mootools, to overcome you can use JQuery noConflict

```
var JQ=jQuery.noConflict();
JQ(document).ready(function(){
    JQ("p").addClass("hyphenate");
});
```